# Application crashes after I change the mxnet model

Tags: java, android, neural-network, mxnet

### Problem

I have tried to replace the Mxnet models in [WhatsThis](https://github.com/Leliana/WhatsThis) with my own Caffe models that I ported to Mxnet with https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn . When I run the application, I get a white screen  with no elements and the application crashes. Please advise. Assume that the model is correct as it works perfectly on a PC Mxnet environment. I only changed the model, did nothing else to get this behavior.

### Solutions that I tried

- Change the input shape ( model is set for 1,3,128,128) - problem remains

### Files used

[symbol.json](https://github.com/Leliana/WhatsThis/files/21153/symbol.json.txt)

### Error log

[Log](https://pastebin.com/raw/TEY3ZD0R) (full error log pasted to pastebin due to stack overflow's limits)

```
06-20 10:27:24.335 3960-3960/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
...
```

Comment: What is the error message you receive when your app crashes?

Comment: @Sergei , thanks for the comment I updated the question with the log from logcat. You can find the log here: [log](https://pastebin.com/raw/TEY3ZD0R)

Comment: First error is "Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory" - I don't really know what this file is. The next from that is MxnetException is not found, so maybe there is something wrong with MXNet installation on Androdi? Have you tried to run some really simple neural network on android to make sure that the Android version of it works?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the application works using the models provided in the repository, to confirm that Android can use the MXNet library correctly. Use the instructions on how to build the MXNet Amalgamation [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/amalgamation) if things are not working with the default models.

You could also try some other methods of converting your model. [ONNX](https://github.com/onnx/onnx#installation) is supported by MXNet and given you're converting a Caffe model, you should be able to use the [MXNet Caffe Converter](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/tree/master/tools/caffe_converter) too.